# Excel Copy certain values of Column to another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to copy certain values of column to another sheet, but it's not working.

The code I am using is:

```
Worksheets("Report").Range(".Cells(x, 1)", ".Cells(x, 2)", ".Cells(x, 4)", ".Cells(x, 6)", ".Cells(x, 9):.Cells(x, 13)").Copy
```

Comment: Please always specify what kind of error you are experiencing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `Range` wrong in two ways:

1) `Range` has only one or two arguments. The usage is either

```
Range(someAddress)
```

where `someAddress` is a String like `"A1"`, `"A1:B2` or even unions like `"A1:B2,C3"` or

```
Range(startCell, endCell)
```

where `startCell` and `endCell` are the first and last cells of the range. They can be supplied either by address (`"A1"`) or by range object (`Cells(1,1)`).

Note that you can also pass ranges with multiple cells but I am not completely sure how it acts then.

2) You are putting your arguments in quotes, making them strings. That means that you don't pass a cell reference to `Range` but the string `".Cells(x, 1)"` (not even x is replaced).

---

Now to create a range from multiple cells you can use `Union`

```
Union(.Cells(x, 1), .Cells(x, 2), ... )
```

or create an address string using the cells addresses

```
.Range(.Cells(x, 1).Address & "," & .Cells(x, 2).Address & "," & ...)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but it shows an error message that this objext doesn't support this method or property when I code like this `.Union(.Cells(x, 1), .Cells(x, 2), .Cells(x, 4)).Copy`

Comment: You need use `Union` by itself, not as a method of the worksheet (which is your `With` block variable I assume). Note that there is no point before `Union` in my example.